# How to use Mongo aggregate to create distinct items from array

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am having trouble understanding how to use aggregate pipelines in Mongo.

Given the list following documents:

```js
db.dishes.insertMany([
    {_id: "Vanilla Sundae", keywords: ["vanilla", "ice cream", "desert"] },
    {_id: "Vanilla Cake", keywords: ["vanilla", "cake", "baking", "desert"] },
    {_id: "Chocolate Cake", keywords: ["chocolate", "cake", "baking", "desert"] }
])
```

How do I create an aggregate that would return a list of distinct keywords and counts of docs by `keywords`:

```js
[
    {"_id": "vanilla", "count": 2},
    {"_id": "ice cream", "count": 1},
    {"_id": "desert", "count": 3},
    {"_id": "baking", "count": 2},
    {"_id": "cake", "count": 2},
    {"_id": "chocolate", "count": 1}
]
```

Comment: Does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` and `$group` to deconstruct and reconstruct the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {  $unwind: "$keywords" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$keywords",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lBX9r0C5gVz)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use unwind combined with group operator to achieve this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { "$unwind": { path: "$keywords" } }, { "$group": { "_id": "$keywords", "count": { $sum: 1 } } }, ])
```

This should do the trick! :)

I'm attaching the MongoDB playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/COhWh3NAhdi).